# Role inheritance by granting one role to another does not work

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, dbeaver

```
DROP OWNED BY user_a;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS user_a;
CREATE ROLE user_a WITH
    NOSUPERUSER
    INHERIT
    NOCREATEDB
    NOCREATEROLE
    NOREPLICATION
    PASSWORD '***'
;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO user_a; 
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO user_a;

DROP ROLE IF EXISTS user_b;
CREATE ROLE user_b WITH
    LOGIN
    NOSUPERUSER
    INHERIT
    NOCREATEDB
    NOCREATEROLE
    NOREPLICATION
    PASSWORD '***';

GRANT user_a TO user_b WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Executing this code, I expect user_b to have select right on all tables in myschema, but he doesn't have them. What did I forget?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: actually it is Postgres 9.6 but that doesnt change anything I assume

Comment: Which is also no longer supported ;) - Do the tables already exist in `myschema` or are they created _after_ the grant has been made?

Comment: the tables already exist.

Comment: That should work. Please show a complete self-contained test case, including `CREATE TABLE`, the failing `SELECT` and the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out after to much research: user_b has the rights of user_a, but my database client, DBeaver, won't display that. It's simply a display bug of DBeaver.